# Does adding uniquing constraints to core data model requires a new model version?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios9

I read this -

> Since a model describes the structure of the data in a persistent
>   store, changing any parts of a model that alters the schema renders it
>   incompatible with (and so unable to open) the stores it previously
>   created. If you change your schema, you therefore need to migrate the
>   data in existing stores to new version (see Core Data Model Versioning
>   and Data Migration Programming Guide). For example, if you add a new
>   entity or a new attribute to an existing entity, you will not be able
>   to open old stores; if you add a validation constraint or set a new
>   default value for an attribute, you will be able to open old stores.

I Sounds to me I should not have a problem to do so as I am not changing the schema. Any input?

Thanks